# When does the Town Shield kick in after an attack?

Tags: clash-of-clans

i've noticed when i get attacked or when i attack a Town Shiled is deployed (at no cost when it was on myself) for 12-16 hours. In an 9 hours period i was attacked twice.

I am wondering when this shield is deployed after an attack or if it's possible for 2 people to attack one town at the same time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The automatic shield is deployed when [certain conditions are met](http://clashofclans.wikia.com/wiki/Shields):

> When 40% of your village or your Town Hall is destroyed in a raid, you will get a 12-hour shield. When 90% or more buildings are destroyed you will get a 16-hour shield instead (these two shields cannot be stacked together).

For the most part, you'll see shields deployed when you lose a battle, as opposed to a successful defense.  There are some corner cases (ie, Town Hall intact and 40-49% of the buildings destroyed) where you can both win *and* get a shield.

As far as I know, there's only one raid allowed on your town at a time.  Thus, if you trigger an automatic shield as a result of a raid, you should be granted immediate protection against further raids.

Comment: But Ive been attacked 2 times in about 10 mins and i lost both raids (with my farming base)? how is this possible?

Comment: This is no longer applicable as they changed the shield rules since this post was made.

Answer (score 0):

Well this was posted at the end of November in 2015, so it's more recent.

https://forum.supercell.com/showthread.php/918490-From-the-Dev-s-Desk-Shields-Part-I-Attacking-and-Defending

Basically, 2 conditions have to be met.

## 1. More than 30% destroyed.

The attack has to do more than 30% damage to your base. Town Halls no longer give you a shield by themselves.

So if someone only destroyed your Town Hall, you would not receive a shield.

You also get:

A 12 hour shield at 30%
A 14 hour shield at 60%
A 16 hour shield at 90%

## 2. The attack must use 1/3 of the maximum full army of the Town Hall level of the attacker.

Heroes count as 25.

Ex.

If the defending player is TH7, then the max army camp level is 6, which is 50 / camp, plus an hero, which is 25.

So an attacker must use 225/3 - 75 troop value - Even if they don't have a hero or their army camps aren't level 6.